# I am having trouble removing new lines from text in a shell script (using sed and grep)

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, command-line-interface, zsh

**I am using zsh on macOS**

I have a shell script that produces a text file with speedtest results in the following layout:

```
 Download:    63.57 Mbps (data used: 69.3 MB)                               

 Upload:    16.11 Mbps (data used: 23.0 MB)
```

I can manipulate the layout and produce this:

```
↓ 63.57 Mbps | 
↑ 16.11 Mbps
```

Note the line break before the first line of text and the one after the pipe. In the Terminal only the final line is printed out: `↑ 16.11 Mbps`

The script to transform the input is this:

```
DOWNLOAD=$(cat ~/Terminal_Projects/temp_speedtest_result.txt | grep Download | sed 's/   Download:    /↓ /g' | sed 's/ (data used: //g' | sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9] MB)//g' | sed 's/\n\r\t//')
UPLOAD=$(cat ~/Terminal_Projects/temp_speedtest_result.txt | grep Upload | sed 's/     Upload:    /↑ /g' | sed 's/ (data used: //g' | sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9] MB)//g' | tr '\n' ' ')
RESULT=$DOWNLOAD" | "$UPLOAD
echo $RESULT
```

I used multiple instances of sed because I couldn't get it to work in just one instance.  You may know how to get it to work.

What I want to do is output the DOWNLOAD and UPLOAD variables on a single line.  I have another very similar script that achieves that with exactly the same manipulation of variables.

What I have tried:

Using RESULT="$DOWNLOAD | $UPLOAD"

Using RESULT="${DOWNLOAD} | ${UPLOAD}"

Using `tr '\n' ' '` instead of the sed command to remove \n

I tried removing the up and down arrows in case those symbols aren't supported - same behaviour.

I have tried using sed on the RESULT variable to try removing new lines.  I also tried writing the contents of the RESULT variable to a new temp txt file and then retrieving the contents of the file and using grep to extract the results one by one in the hope the new lines would not be copied.  Didn't work for me.
It *looks like* there are line breaks that I have been unable to remove but I could be wrong.

I am new to command line and shell scripts.  Trying to apply my very limited knowledge to a new scenario.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want it to look like in case you have multiple `Download` or `Upload` lines in the input file? Or is that guaranteed to never happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr` seems to do the job and `echo -n "$UPLOAD"` shows on a single line, so I think you're on the right track and only need to fix the `DOWNLOAD` part.

I suggest you simplify the script a bit using something along these lines:

```
INPUT_FILE="~/Terminal_Projects/temp_speedtest_result.txt"

DOWNLOAD="$(grep Download $INPUT_FILE | awk '{print "↓" $2 " " $3}' | tr '\n' ' ')"
UPLOAD="$(grep Upload $INPUT_FILE | awk '{print "↓" $2 " " $3}' | tr '\n' ' ')"

echo "$DOWNLOAD | $UPLOAD"
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  I can now see down and upload speeds in my menu bar!  It seems I need to get more familiar with `awk`.  I've implemented the code you suggested with a couple of minor edits ↑ in the upload string and I appended `sed 's/Upload://g'` and download equivalent since I want to shorten the string by replacing "Upload:" with "↑".  Thanks for being such a great help.

Comment: You could eliminate the grep by putting the patterns in the awk invocation: awk '/Download/ {print....}' $INPUT_FILE | tr...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
RESULT="$(grep -Ew '(Down|Up)load' <~/Terminal_Projects/temp_speedtest_result.txt | tr '\n' ' ')"
```

? This is more efficient (only one *grep* and *tr* process needed) and also fixes the bug you have in your solution by your use of a pipe in `RESULT=$DOWNLOAD" | "$UPLOAD` (which should have brought up an error message).

Comment: Sorry, this still gives me a result across multiple lines, but yes I take the point that my initial string extraction is inefficient because I extract similar strings twice.

Comment: Can't be, because the `tr` removes the newlines. You can try it with the example `RESULT=$((echo a1 ; echo b1) |tr '\n' ' ')`, which sets `RESULT` to `a1 b1` (without newlines).

Comment: Yeah your script works as expected.  I agree that the tr should work, I even think it should have worked on my original script, which is why I was scratching my head for hours before I finally conceded and wrote my question up here.  I think there must be something else going on; maybe it isn't actually related to removal of new lines - but I'm such a newb that I don't know.

Comment: @Dan : Hard to say, since in your question, you are presenting a variety of attempts to the problem, with various bugs, and there is no clear correct solution to see. If my suggestion does what you are looking for, would you consider accepting it as correct answer?

Comment: Costi's answer (above) works, I marked that as correct already.  As you say technically your answer removes line breaks too - just not in my exact situation for some reason.  I just tried marking yours as correct too but SO seems to allow only one correct solution per quesiton.  So I want to leave Costi's as the correct answer as it solves the problem I presented.